# How to add dynamically generated inline javascript using Rails 3.1 and Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am using Rails 3.1 and Haml. What is the best way to add inline javascript that is generated in something such as a form_for block. I tried the following:

In layouts/application.html.haml,

```
...
:javascript
  yield(:jstemplates)
...
```

And in my form_for block,

```
...
= content_for :jstemplates do
  = "var my_var='#{generate_template(form, :my_field)}'"
...
```

Instead, I had to do the following:

```
...
:javascript
  #{@my_javascript}
...
```

and

```
...
- @my_javascript = capture_haml do
  var my_var='#{generate_template(form,:my_field)}'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

i usually have the following on the bottom of my application layout:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    #{yield :javascript}
  });
```

when i have view-specific javascript i write it directly into the view like so:

```
- content_for :javascript do
  :plain
    doSomeFunkyStuffWithRailsParameters( #{@whatever.title} );
```